# using the result from jQuery into C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have this function in jquery which has the result array and how can I get this result array to C# code. Can anyone help me regarding this.

```
 function generateData() {
 var result = $('#accordion').sortable('toArray');
 }
```

Comment: jQuery is a client-side language while C# is a Server-Side one . You should sent it back to the server

Comment: could you please let me know how I could send it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this asynchronously through a web method call from script, such that you define a web method appropriately, then call and handle the data and potential return value, as desired. For example:

Defining a web method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string HandleData(object[] data)
{
    //handle data
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Defining a reusable jQuery script method to handle web method calls:

```
function ExecutePageMethod(page, fn, paramArray, successFn, errorFn) {
    var paramList = '';
    if (paramArray.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i += 2) {
            if (paramList.length > 0) paramList += ',';
            paramList += '"' + paramArray[i] + '":"' + paramArray[i + 1] + '"';
        }
    }
    paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: page + "/" + fn,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: paramList,
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    });
}
```

And, of course, the call itself:

```
ExecutePageMethod("Default.aspx", "HandleData", 
    ["data", result], successCallback, failureCallback);
```

Naturally we now need to make sure our callback methods exist:

```
function successCallback(result) {
    var parsedResult = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);
}

function failureCallback(result) {

}
```

Comment: I have copied the webmethod into code behind and the rest functions into script file where I called my ExecutePageMethod, but its not going to the success callback function

Comment: Could you also please let me know if this is the script to send array values from jquery script to c# code behind

Comment: Is `failureCallback` being called? ...And the script will send the parameters as a key:value array, which must align with the signature of the web method.

Comment: Then you should have access to an error message in the result.

Comment: No my result array returns a list of div id's (section_1,section_2,section_3) of the accordians. I needed to pass these values to the codebehind

Comment: It does not suite the key value pairs where my id is like section_1 and so on.. so is there any way I could send this

Comment: This is the paramList value that is being passed to the ajax  {"data":"section_1,section_2,section_3"}

Answer (score 1):

Use a hiddenfield to store the result..

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hfResult" runat="server" />
```

JQuery

```
$('hfResult').val(result);
```

C#

```
String result = hfResult.Value;
```

Note that a hiddenField only holds a string, so you might need to use some kind of seperator to seperate your array objects..