# keyup event called database function and populate listbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a webpage in ASP.NET with the following code, **Default.aspx**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="SearchHandler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ListBox ID="listbox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my **SearchHandler.js**, I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        //..do something here and populate listbox from database query result.
        //..call C# function GetItems(), passing input as parameter and use to populate ListBox.
    });
});
```

In **Functions.cs**:

```
public class Functions
{
   Database db = new Database();   
   public List<string> GetItems(string searchinput) 
   {
      List<string> items = db.DoSomething(searchinput);
      return items;
   }
}
```

Sorry I'm pretty new to this, but how would I complete the code above to populate the listbox on the same page? Basically the listbox would have its content refreshed everytime the user 'keys up' in the textbox. I would like to call a C# function `GetItems()` from the **Functions.cs** class file.

NEW EDIT:

Basically `GetItems()` takes a key input, everytime a key is pressed, it would fire a database query to retrieve the relevant records. I have a table like below (for example):

```
TableA
Name       Country
Tom        England
Bill       USA
John       Australia
Jim        China
Harry      Belgium
Johnathan  France
```

So when someone enters "John" in the search box, 'Australia' and 'France' would be in the listbox.

```
SELECT Country FROM TableA WHERE Name LIKE '%John%'
```

EDIT 21/06/12: If I were to not use the KeyUp event and use a button event instead, would this make it a better scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using the result from jQuery into C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740545/using-the-result-from-jquery-into-c-sharp) - the other way around but the principle is the same.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Are you able to provide an example as I don't really understand the reference posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My first response here is do not do it this way. Making a DB call every time someone enters a letter on a list will be very expensive for your DB access, and will drag your performance down something hideous. Even if you use an ajax call - there is no way you can get the responses back in a time that would work. So I would give you some broad suggestions:

1. How many entries could there be? Could you load them into a JS array, and search them within JS? Probably not, otherwise you wouldn't need to do this process.
2. Get the list from the DB once, and store it as a serialised object. Then search this object for the relevant options. Load this data in site initialisation.
3. Once you have entered a character - or maybe 2, depending on your data - do an ajax call to get the entire relevant list of options. From there on, use this list in JS to restrict based on further input.

Tweak this until it works well. I can give more details on any particular piece of this if required.

EDIT based on more details.

I would suggest that on the first key press, you load all the entries relevant for this single character. From there onwards, you search the loaded list for matches, narrowing it down from there.

You should kick off an ajax query to get all of the references the first time, and do nothing else with the entries until this returns.

You might also want to load the entire list into memory on the app load, and take a subset of this when needed. Possibly, take 26 entries one for each initial character, but that is probably OTT for this size. It might depend on the performance you get from the db calls and the selections.

This is quite complex, but should produce you a respondent interface that does what you need.

Comment: Hi Schroedingers Cat, data at the moment is only 350 records, but this is dynamic data, so there could be more or could be less. Is option 1 compatible? For option 2, I don't quite understand how the listbox would be updated after input, we refresh the whole page? For option 3, would that mean getting every record and chucking it into some sort of JS array and then searching on this instead?

Comment: They are not options, they are points. 2 would not be appropriate if the data is dynamic. 3 would mean getting a subset of the data into a js array - only those entries starting with the typed entries. If you are loading them all into the listbox anyway, can you not search them, rather than having to go back to the server?

Comment: I have updated my original question. I'm not sure if that clarifies further what I am trying to achieve. Or if you can point me in the right direction in achieving this sort of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure but you may be looking for something like this http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Edit: Nevermind I misread your question, however i would look around the ajax library to see if you can find something suitable or something you can adapt to your needs. Good luck.

Edit: If you enclose your list in an updatepanel you can refresh it on that event.
http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyzhao/archive/2008/04/26/refresh-the-updatepanel-using-javascript-code.aspx